# Where to hook in to alter View output in Laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel, response

For some kind of output filter, I need to access the final rendered output string that includes both view data as well as 'hardcoded' text in the view file.

For example:

**welcome.blade.php**

```
<div>This is bad and you are {{ $variable }}</div>
```

**controller, composer, or something else that attaches variables**

```
view()->with('variable', 'bad')
```

The final output would be

```
<div>This is bad and you are bad</div>
```

But now let's pretend we want to replace each instance of 'bad' with 'good', so we get:

```
<div>This is good and you are good</div>
```

Altering view data is well supported, but how to apply some altering logic to the fully rendered content? (since I think this is the only way to also alter contents of a view file itself?)

Note: *if and only if possible*, I'd prefer a 'hook-in' solution instead of an 'extend-core' one..

Comment: Am i understanding you right, you don't want to alter your view data within the view by for example using blade syntax, but you would prefer to organize that logic into a location from outside the view. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes, since the altering logic should apply to both view data and hardcoded text in a view file. It'll behave like an ultimate content filter as shown in the example.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the **CompilerEngine** (*Illuminate\View\Engines\CompilerEngine*).
You could use it to get the evaluated contents of a view by using the get method.
Maybe combine that with a registered ServiceProvider to manipulate the views content. Also check out the **BladeCompiler** maybe you can combine those.

But trying to change hardcoded text seems a bit odd. Why not just use variables in the first place. I mean why is it hardcoded if you want to change it afterwards?

Comment: It seems the only way would be by extending core classes and replacing them. I think I'll go with a default composer then and apply the altering function straight to the hardcoded text part... (the goal of this question was to NOT think about applying a function to hardcoded text in such a way that it applies automatically).